# Changing Values if ID Has a Certain Value in Any Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, window-functions

I have two columns in my table. One column is ID, and the other is TestResult. There are rows with the same ID in this table. Let's say TestResult can be either 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Pending', or 'Unknown'. So the same ID can show 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Pending', or 'Unknown'.

Here is what I want output to show. If the ID contains 'Positive' IN ANY ROW, I want that ID to show 'Positive'. Otherwise it remains unchanged.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to show each ID only once, or what? It's not very clear. I agree, sample data and expected query results would help a lot

Comment: If an ID has four rows, do you want to show all four rows or just one "summary" one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can use window functions and a `case` expression:

```
select
    id,
    case when max(case when test_result = 'Positive' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) = 1
        then 'Positive'
        else testResult
    end testResult
from mytable
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but I guess this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @BRuppert, please mark it as answer. so it is helpful for others in future

Answer (score 1):

The answer with the CASE & Window Functions work well ... however here's an option using a subquery.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData

SELECT * INTO #TestData FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'Positive'),
    (2, 'Positive'),
    (2, 'Negative'),
    (3, 'Unknown'),
    (3, 'Negative'),
    (3, 'Positive'),
    (4, 'Pending'),
    (4, 'Positive'),
    (5, 'Unknown'),
    (6, 'Negative'),
    (7, 'Unknown'),
    (7, 'Positive'),
    (8, 'Positive')
) S(ID, TestResult)

-- Display Test Result Data
SELECT ID, TestResult FROM #TestData

-- Display Query Proposal
SELECT
    ID,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TestData T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.TestResult = 'Positive') THEN 'Positive' ELSE T1.TestResult END
FROM
    #TestData T1
```